# How to set parindent in apa class?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, apa-style

Usually one can adjust paragraph indent with

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

but that fails for the **apa** class. Is there another way to get rid of this indents in this class?

Comment: The class might set `\parindent` at the begin of the document. Did you tried changing it after `\begin{document}`?

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel you should turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I must qualify my comment-- see my answer.

Comment: He guys thank fo the help. After begindocument works now :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must qualify my comment.

I used the two following examples to test my statement and I noticed that the command:

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

in the preamble will do the job.

test-file `apa.cls`

```
\documentclass[english]{apa}
\usepackage{babel,blindtext}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0pt}
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

test-file `apa6.cls`

```
\documentclass[english]{apa6}
\usepackage{babel,blindtext}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0pt}
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

In the next run I noticed that `\maketitle` set a new paragraph indention at the end of definition.

```
\documentclass[english]{apa}
\usepackage{babel,blindtext}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0pt}
\author{Name}
\title{MWE}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Based on this MWE (that is your task) you have to change `\parindent` after `\maketitle`

---

**Proof:** 
A [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) ist the best way to illustrate a problem.  q.e.d.

Comment: Thanks it definitively just works after begin{document} and after making some title stuff. `\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\maketitle
\doublespacing
\pagestyle{headings}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`